# Integrate an iframe in user status

Tags: facebook, html, post, iframe, status

Exploring the obscur posts on this forum, I didn't found any convenient answer. I'm developping a player widget in HTML5 and I'd like to add a "share" functionality which would display, in the same way than soundcloud does for ex, in the user's status, the playable widget and not only a link. I would like it fully playable in the status update. Is it possible to publish an iframe in the status and not only a text/link... ?

Comment: No, it’s not. Facebook decides, what (Open Graph) content to display in what way and form. Pushing music to timeline, so that it’s actually playable right there, is AFAIK only available for a few white-listed partners at the moment.